# I need a in-memory index like Sphinx

Tags: indexing, sphinx, sharding, in-memory-database

i use mongodb to store my data, but for searching mongodb is too much slow! Actually i use sphinx to search the data but sphinx badly handle the sharding of the data (we must shard the database by ourself, it's hard). so i m looking for an in memory index like sphinx who can shard the data by himself on all servers it's will have and keep all the data in memory to be super fast.

thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

---

First of all, Sphinx is not in-memory-database. It is full-text search engine, which stores full-text indexes on the disk.
If I understand correctly, you mean not sharding (part of data on one server, part of data on another server), but replication (all data on one server, all data on another server). Both of this tasks Sphinx solves perfectly - you just need to make distributed index, it is not hard.

If you need full-text index, look at Elasticsearch.
If you need key-value index, look at Redis - super fast in-memory persistent database, which has some useful data types and operations. Replication if very simple, Sharding is possible using Twemproxy.